# Single root directed acyclic graph cycle detection

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, topological-sort

The graph has only one root. And it is saved in the following format:

```
0 -> 1,
0 -> 2,
1 -> 3,
1 -> 4,
2 -> 4,
2 -> 5,
4 -> 5,
5 -> 2 (This is the cycle)
```

What is the most efficient way to detect if there exists at least one cycle in the graph using Java? Thanks!

[image: example]

Comment: You can use the Kahn algorithm (or alternatively, DFS) to find a topological sorting of the directed graph. If topological sorting cannot be found, then there is a cycle. Both approaches have running time linear in the number of nodes plus the number of edges, i.e. O(|V| + |E|).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments probably some sort of DFS like

```
SET isCyclic to false
DFS(node)
   IF isCyclic is true THEN 
       RETURN
   FOR each neighbor in node.neighbors
       IF node.visited is true THEN
           SET isCyclic to true
           RETURN
       SET neighbor.visited to true
       DFS(neighbor)
```